# How to get the original text back from a pyparsing token

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a text of the form `name(sum(value1,sum(value2,value3)), "sumname")` and pyparsing returns the appropiate tokens, however, I am interested in getting the real text back and I cannot find how.

I have tried setParseAction with a function, but since it only returns string and location, I cannot cope with the trailing part.
like, I will only get:

```
"sum(value2,value3)), "sumname")"
"sum(value1,sum(value2,value3)), "sumname")"
"name(sum(value1,sum(value2,value3)), "sumname")"
```

And this is not ideal, I do not want to reparse the string manually to get the actual original string.

The way I am trying atm is:

```
tokens = grammar.parseString(target_string)  
print >>sys.stderr, pyparsing.originalTextFor(tokens)
```

But this does not really work:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setParseAction'
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your expression in the pyparsing helper `originalTextFor`.

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, originalTextFor

sample = '<tag attr1="A1" attr2="B3">'

openTag = makeHTMLTags('tag')[0]

# the expression returned by makeHTMLTags parses the tag and 
# attributes into a list (along with a series of helpful 
# results names)
print (openTag.parseString(sample).asList())

# prints
# ['tag', ['attr1', 'A1'], ['attr2', 'B3'], False]

# wrap in 'originalTextFor' to get back the original source text
print (originalTextFor(openTag).parseString(sample).asList())

# prints
# ['<tag attr1="A1" attr2="B3">']
```

Comment: Hi, this fails for me `tokens = grammar.parseString(target_string)` 
`print >>sys.stderr, pyparsing.originalTextFor(tokens)` I suspect it is because parseString returns ParseResults and not ParseElements

Comment: `originalTextFor` wraps the grammar, not the results. Try `originalTextFor(grammar).parseString(tokens)`.

Comment: I see that, but yet, you are supplying the original string all the time, while all I have is the result of parseString, and I need the string back. you pass a string to parseString, makes sense, but I don't have a string, just a collection of tokens.

Comment: My mistake - should be: `originalTextFor(grammar).parseString(target_string)`. 

`originalTextFor` is a modifier to the grammar that changes its behavior at parse time. After the grammar matches, `originalTextFor` replaces whatever it is that the grammar returns with the original text that the grammar matched. You have to modify the parse-time behavior, because that is the only time when you have access to the exact start/stop locations while parsing the grammar expression.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish by getting the original matching text, you might find better solutions using `scanString` or `transformString`:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, replaceWith

sample = '<other><div></div><tag attr1="A1" attr2="B3"><something>'
openTag = makeHTMLTags('tag')[0]

# grammar.scanString is a generator, yielding tokens,start,end tuples
# from the start:end values you can slice the original text from the
# source string
for tokens,start,end in openTag.scanString(sample):
    print tokens.dump()
    print sample[start:end]

# if your goal in getting the original data is to do some kind of string
# replacement, use transformString - here we convert all <TAG> tags to <REPLACE> tags
print openTag.setParseAction(replaceWith("<REPLACE>")).transformString(sample)
```

prints:

```
['tag', ['attr1', 'A1'], ['attr2', 'B3'], False]
- attr1: A1
- attr2: B3
- empty: False
- startTag: ['tag', ['attr1', 'A1'], ['attr2', 'B3'], False]
  - attr1: A1
  - attr2: B3
  - empty: False
  - tag: tag
- tag: tag
<tag attr1="A1" attr2="B3">
<other><div></div><REPLACE><something>
```

Follow these links for more info on [scanString](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html?highlight=scanString#pyparsing.ParserElement.scanString) and [transformString](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html?highlight=transformString#pyparsing.ParserElement.transformString).

Comment: you might want to add links to the API description and more details on how the two functions work. I couldn't understand what is going on and why things behave as described and i am missing the motivation why these two somewhat obscure functions are better than working with the tokens in the parseResults or an action directly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added the doc links as you suggested. I had hoped that the embedded comments would give explanation on what is going on in this script, but I guess they assume too much awareness of how pyparsing works.

Comment: More than two year laster i still have no clue how to get the original string back from a parseresult. I get TypeError: Cannot combine element of type ParseResults with ParserElement and do not understand what strange internal behavior ParseResults wants to achieve.