# Parsing nested lists and returning original strings for every valid list

Tags: python, nested, pyparsing

Suppose I have a string `s = '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'`, which has a structure of nested lists. I would like to have an hierarchical representation for it, while being able to access the sub-strings corresponding to the valid sub-lists. For simplicity, let's forget about the hierarchy, and I just want a list of sub-strings corresponding to valid sub-lists, something like:

```
['{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}', '{bc}', '{d{e}}', '{e}']
```

Using `nestedExpr`, one can obtain the nested structure, which includes all valid sub-lists:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

s = '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'
not_braces = pp.CharsNotIn('{}')
expr = pp.nestedExpr('{', '}', content=not_braces)
res = expr('L0 Contents').parseString(s)
print(res.dump())
```

prints:

```
[['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']]
- L0 Contents: [['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']]
  [0]:
    ['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']
    [0]:
      aaaa
    [1]:
      ['bc']
    [2]:
      xx
    [3]:
      ['d', ['e']]
      [0]:
        d
      [1]:
        ['e']
    [4]:
      f
```

In order to obtain the original string representation for a parsed element, I have to wrap it into `pyparsing.originalTextFor()`. However, this will remove all sub-lists from the result:

```py
s = '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'
not_braces = pp.CharsNotIn('{}')
expr = pp.nestedExpr('{', '}', content=not_braces)
res = pp.originalTextFor(expr)('L0 Contents').parseString(s)
print(res.dump())
```

prints:

```
['{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}']
- L0 Contents: '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'
```

In effect, the `originalTextFor()` wrapper flattened out everything that was inside it.

**The question.** Is there an alternative to `originalTextFor()` that keeps the structure of its child parse elements? (It would be nice to have a non-discarding analogue, which could be used for creation of named tokens for parsed sub-expressions)

Note that `scanString()` will only give me the level 0 sub-lists, and will not look inside. I guess, I could use `setParseAction()`, but the mode of internal operation of `ParserElement`'s is not documented, and I haven't had a chance to dig into the source code yet. Thanks!

Update 1. Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39885391/11932910 https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411455/11932910

Comment: What's the output you're interested in?

Comment: I hope you don't have to dig into the pyparsing internals to get this kind of thing. Parse actions can maniipulate the parsed results and then give them back to pyparsing as modified. Also, you can learn more about the breadth of classes and helpers at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/pyparsing_2.4.6/pyparsing.html

Comment: @Roy2012 The output I am interested in is in the first code blockquote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `originalTextFor`, wrap your `nestedExpr` expression in `locatedExpr`:

```
import pyparsing as pp
parser = pp.locatedExpr(pp.nestedExpr('{','}'))
```

`locatedExpr` will return a 3-element ParseResults:

- start location
- parsed value
- end location

You can then attach a parse action to this parser to modify the parsed tokens in place, and add your own `original_string` named result, containing the original text as sliced from the input string:

```
def extract_original_text(st, loc, tokens):
    start, tokens[:], end = tokens[0]
    tokens['original_string'] = st[start:end]
parser.addParseAction(extract_original_text)
```

Now use this parser to parse and dump the results:

```
result = parser.parseString(s)
print(result.dump())
```

Prints:

```
['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']
- original_string: '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'
```

And access the `original_string` result using:

```
print(result.original_string)
```

**EDIT - how to attach original_string to each nested substructure**

To maintain the original strings on the sub-structures requires a bit more work than can be done in just `nested_expr`. You pretty much have to implement your own recursive parser.

To implement your own version of `nested_expr`, you'll start with something like this:

```
LBRACE, RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress, "{}")
expr = pp.Forward()

term = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
expr_group = pp.Group(LBRACE + expr + RBRACE)
expr_content = term | expr_group

expr <<= expr_content[...]

print(expr.parseString(sample).dump())
```

This will dump out the parsed results, without the 'original_string' names:

```
{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}
[['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']]
[0]:
  ['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']
  [0]:
    aaaa
  [1]:
    ['bc']
  [2]:
    xx
  [3]:
    ['d', ['e']]
    [0]:
      d
    [1]:
      ['e']
  [4]:
    f
```

To add the 'original_string' names, we first change the `Group` to the `locatedExpr` wrapper.

```
expr_group = pp.locatedExpr(LBRACE + expr + RBRACE)
```

This will add the start and end locations to each nested subgroup (which is not accessible to you when using `nestedExpr`).

```
{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}
[[0, 'aaaa', [5, 'bc', 9], 'xx', [11, 'd', [13, 'e', 16], 17], 'f', 19]]
[0]:
  [0, 'aaaa', [5, 'bc', 9], 'xx', [11, 'd', [13, 'e', 16], 17], 'f', 19]
  - locn_end: 19
  - locn_start: 0
  - value: ['aaaa', [5, 'bc', 9], 'xx', [11, 'd', [13, 'e', 16], 17], 'f']
    [0]:
      aaaa
    [1]:
      [5, 'bc', 9]
      - locn_end: 9
      - locn_start: 5
      - value: ['bc']
...
```

Our parse action is now more complicated also.

```
def extract_original_text(st, loc, tokens):
    # pop/delete names and list items inserted by locatedExpr
    # (save start and end locations to local vars)
    tt = tokens[0]
    start = tt.pop("locn_start")
    end = tt.pop("locn_end")
    tt.pop("value")
    del tt[0]
    del tt[-1]

    # add 'original_string' results name
    orig_string = st[start:end]
    tt['original_string'] = orig_string

expr_group.addParseAction(extract_original_text)
```

With this change, you will now get this structure:

```
{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}
[['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']]
[0]:
  ['aaaa', ['bc'], 'xx', ['d', ['e']], 'f']
  - original_string: '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'
  [0]:
    aaaa
  [1]:
    ['bc']
    - original_string: '{bc}'
  [2]:
    xx
  [3]:
    ['d', ['e']]
    - original_string: '{d{e}}'
    [0]:
      d
    [1]:
      ['e']
      - original_string: '{e}'
  [4]:
    f
```

Note: There is a limitation in the current version of ParseResults.dump that only shows keys *or* subitems, but not both - this output requires a fix that removes that limitation, to be released in next pyparsing version. But even though dump() does not show these substructures, they are there in your actual structure, as you can see if you print out the repr of the results:

```
print(repr(result[0]))

(['aaaa', (['bc'], {'original_string': '{bc}'}), 'xx', (['d', (['e'], {'original_string': '{e}'})], {'original_string': '{d{e}}'}), 'f'], {'original_string': '{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'})
```

Comment: Is it possible to accumulate the original sub-strings recursively, so that I get `'{aaaa{bc}xx{d{e}}f}'` as well as `'{bc}'` (and so on) in the result?